# Gravitons with tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

Gravitons (in Feynman diagrams) are basically two wavy lines. I am interested in this type of diagram here:

[image: Similar diagram, but with photon line.]

However, the single wavy line should become a double wavy line. The code used to generate the above image is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[{[]}]{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[layered layout,inline=(a.base),horizontal=a to c] {
a -- [charged scalar,momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2]\(p\)}] b -- [double,double distance=0.5ex, photon, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1.5cm,momentum={[arrow shorten=0.35]\(k\)}] b,
b -- [charged scalar,momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2]\(p\)}] c,
};

\end{document}
```

I added a `double,double distance=0.5ex` to the photon propagator, but apparently the `photon` overrides that style. Does anybody know how to double the wavy line?

Comment: The feynman package is still tikz. So you can e.g. draw a regular circle and decorate it the way you describe. See the decoration-lib in tikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new key `graviton` using the `snake` decoration and `double`. Options `amplitude`, `segment length`, `pre length` and `post length` can be adjusted to your liking. The `momentum` arrow does not work well with repeating decorations like `snake`, so I made two loops, one with `draw=none` and the momentum arrow, and a second with `graviton`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\tikzset{graviton/.style={decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=1.5mm, pre length=.5mm, post length=.5mm}, double}}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[layered layout,inline=(a.base),horizontal=a to c] {
a -- [charged scalar,momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2]\(p\)}] b -- [draw=none, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1.5cm, text=black, momentum={[arrow shorten=0.35]\(k\)}] b
  -- [graviton, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1.5cm] b -- [charged scalar,momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2]\(p\)}] c,
};

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great. It's a bit odd that the "waviness" is different from the photon line, though, if you compare it closely you can spot some differences.

Comment: @Jens: You can play with the `graviton` decoration if you like. `decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2.13mm}` is a bit closer to the photon, but I liked the look of the pre- and post lengths.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution: draw the path twice, once thick and black and once thin and white:

```
\feynmandiagram[layered layout,inline=(a.base),horizontal=a to c] {
        a -- [charged scalar,momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2]\(p\)}] b -- [double,double distance=0.5ex, photon, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1.5cm, line width=0.05cm] b,
        b -- [photon, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1.5cm, white, text=black, momentum={[arrow shorten=0.35]\(k\)}]
        b -- [charged scalar,momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2]\(p\)}] c,
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and creative idea!

Comment: Not really, It's how double lines are drawn normally, it just happens automatically